# Bootstrap Overlay Menu Change Drag Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, shopify

Okay, so I made an overlay menu in Bootstrap. Problem is, I'm trying to replace the `.ion-drag` class with `.ion-close` when the modal is open, and have it go back to `.ion-drag` when the modal is closed. How do I do that in jQuery? Every solution on the internet doesn't work so far.

My website: https://filthdemo.myshopify.com

Comment: your site isn't loading jquery (according to my console). resource that it's looking for is https://cdn.shopify.com/s/shopify/jquery.js

Comment: @RobWelan fixed

Comment: you're still getting console errors ($ is not defined). According to the source of your page, your custom code is loading prior to jquery itself,
 which is why that console error is appearing. you need your jquery.js?106... script to load after the jquery.min.js script -> here's the current source order... <script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1946/9599/t/15/assets/jquery.js?10624189087370271951" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @RobWelan okay, that should work now...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, keep only `.ion-drag` before opening modal

```
$('.boxed a').toggleClass('ion-drag is-closed')
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in `<head>`

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('nav-active');
  });
</script>
```

and change your `<header>` as

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="toggle-button" id="toggle">
            <span class="bar top"></span>
            <span class="bar middle"></span>
            <span class="bar bottom"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```